# Lift passing data with a Link

Tags: scala, lift

What is the "best" way to pass Data with a Link?

In the moment i save the Data in a SessionVAr and get it out on the other side. But that feels very clumsy. Is there a other way to do that?

```
object activeHw extends SessionVar[Box[Hw]](Empty)

object AddHwScreen extends LiftScreen {
  object hw extends ScreenVar(activeHw.is.getOrElse(Hw.createRecord))
  addFields(() => hw.is)
  def finish() = {
    redirectTo("/hw")
  }
}

class HwSnippet extends StatefulSnippet with PaginatorSnippet[Hw] {
  var dispatch: DispatchIt = {
    case "showAll" => showAll _
  }

  def showAll(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    page.flatMap(hw => {
      (".hwDetail *" #> link ("hw/detail", () => activeHw.set(Full(hw)), Text("Detail")) &
       ".hwSn *" #> hw.sn).apply(xhtml)
    })
  }

  def redirectToHome = {
    redirectTo("/hw")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have:

```
object MyInfo extends RequestVar("nothing")
```

Then:

```
val str = (new java.util.Date).toString
S.redirectTo("/", () => MyInfo.set(str))
```

You capture the value by calculating it before doing the redirectTo, then execute a function that sets a RequestVar to the value.  The RequestVar can be accessed by the target page.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a SessionVar then there's no need to pass it in the link. Just access it in the next Snippet.

**Update:** Sorry, I misread your question. You are already doing that but would rather pass it on the link (as a query parameter?). Generally that isn't the Lift way of doing things: someone could change the value, etc. If you really want to you can add a query param to the link and then access it in the next Snippet with `S.param("the-name")`.